# how to use rpy2 to get n-dim array from python

Tags: python, numpy, rpy2

I want to use python to some calculations and put the array data to r to get some plot.

For 1-dim array, I can use FloatVector to get right answer, but n-dim array error

(run following code)

(2-dim array)
   `import numpy as np 
 from rpy2.robjects.vectors import FloatVector
 x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
 X = FloatVector(x)`

error information:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "D:\Program\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\vectors.py",   line 456, in __init__
 obj = FloatSexpVector(obj)
 ValueError: Error while trying to convert element 0 to a double.`
```

Using numpy2ri could make error in some plot orders(like ggplot2)

I'd like to doing these all in spyder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion mechanism can be your friend:

```
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri

with localconverter(numpy2ri.converter) as cv:
    X = cv.py2ro(x) # convert from *py*thon to *ro*bjects
```

Otherwise, this is happening because rpy2 is trying to iterate through
the sequence `x` (the default behavior without interaction with numpy
requested) and make each element through the iteration an R/rpy2 object.
Here it does not work because `x[i]` is turned to a `FloatVector` and you cannot have a `FloatVector` of `FloatVector` elements (you could have a list of FloatVector though). Explictly, this is what is happening (and you'll trigger the same error):

```
FloatVector([FloatVector(y) for y in x])
```